# Java use 1 billion digits of pi

Tags: java, arrays, list, out-of-memory, pi

I am trying to make a program that will search the first 1 billion digits of pi and will find a user specified number, the problem I am facing is how to use pi...  I have a .txt file that contains pi (I also broke it to 96 different files because java couldn't handle such a big file) all the digits are in the first line....
Code (only to read and save pi using the 96 files):

```
for(int i = 1;i <= 96; i++){
        String filename = "";
        if(i <= 9){
            filename = "res//t//output2_00000" + i + "(500001).txt";
        }else{
            filename = "res//t//output2_0000" + i + "(500001).txt";
        }
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
        ar.add(inFile.nextLine());
    }
    List<String> pi = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<97;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        for(String j : ar.get(i).split("")){
            pi.add(j);
        }
    }
```

This seems to work fine up to a point where it crashes with the following error (the last print statement is 3):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.subSequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Is there a way to overcome that, and is there a way to make it go faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java can handle 1Gb files. It only depends on how you read it.

Comment: Appending the contents of every text file to a string seems like a poor solution. If you've split the string into equal-sized chunks, you know that if the user is searching for the 1 billionth digit that it's not in the first 95 files, so why bother checking them?

Comment: plus then building an array of those digits... ouch. it might only be 1 billion single digit integers, but that's still 1 billion integers in an array, which is going to be MUCH larger than merely "1 billion".

Comment: I have 16Gb of ram, so here's how I would do it: I would launch my JVM with -Xms4096m, read every digit of pi into a StringBuilder (appending line by line), then search for my pattern.

Comment: @Michael i wasnt searching for the n'th digit but rather in which position x (ex. x =1234) is.....thats why it had to search it all :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is likely that you go out of heap memory if you try to load over 1GB of data into the heap. Just check every single file for the search string and then close the file.

Comment: What if the pattern is the last 10 digits of file 1 and the first 10 digits of file 2?

Comment: @SaviourSelf i made it so if the string is bigger than the end of the file , search in the next file too :D

Comment: what if it spans 3 files?

Answer (score 3):

You are not required to load the whole file in memory. With [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), you can open a file, place the cursor at the place you want and read from it :

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(
  new File("/home/adenoyelle/dev/pi.txt"), "r");
raf.seek(1_000_000);
System.out.println(raf.read());
```

Note : `raf.read()` returns a byte of data. You might need to reinterpret it depending on what you need.

Example :

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
  raf.seek(i);
  System.out.println((char)raf.read());
}
```

Output :

```
3
.
1
4
1
5
9
2
6
5
```

Note 2 : As stated by SaviourSelf, if you need to read multiple bytes at a time, prefer `read(byte [] b)`.

Comment: This seems like it would have a LOT of IO calls for OP's issue. I would recommend `read(byte [] b)` instead.

Comment: @SaviourSelf Agree. i thought that the OP only needed to find the nth digit, not several.

Comment: I think this is a good solution; doesn't require a 3rd party library. Plus one.

Comment: Unless I interpreted it wrong, the OP stated a number within the first billion digits, not the nth digit. That number could be `123456789`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't split up the text file: that's the wrong solution, finding a number that's split across a file will be a pain. Of *course* Java can handle large files: how else do you think databases written in Java work?!

Consider using the Apache Commons IO, which gives you a `LineIterator`:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8"/*probably*/);
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

Comment: Not the down voter but I'm wondering how this would work if the search item spanned multiple lines?

Comment: That's a good point: I was assuming the OP would know to keep the previous line in memory. Of course, you'll have to define what a line means if the data tape doesn't contain linebreaks.

Comment: not what i was loking for but +1 because i learned something, thanks!